# EventBus between two fragments - No subscribers registered

Tags: android, android-fragments

Good Day,

To simplify my app loks like that: Only one `Activity`, `Fragment A` and `Fragment B`.

In the `Fragment A` I'm trying to post an empty `ScopeModel` object:

`EventBus.getDefault().post(new ScopeModel());`

After that in my log there is an error:

```
D/Event: No subscribers registered for event class com.commons.library.models.search.ScopeModel
D/Event: No subscribers registered for event class de.greenrobot.event.NoSubscriberEvent
```

But there is subscriber in the `Fragment B`:

```
public void onEventMainThread(ScopeModel model){
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Event!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Q: Where I'm using this to register and unregister EventBus?

```
EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
```

A:

1) In the `Activity` :  `onCreate()` and `onDestroy()`

2) In the `Fragment A` : I don't do that.

3) In the `Fragment B` : `onCreateView()` and `onDestroyView()`

I think there is problem in register/unregister, but how to solve it ?

I simplify my app structure, in general: there is only one activity and a lot of fragments, I'm using EventBus to communicate between fragments and there is only one point where it not working, I'm confused - why ?

Comment: Your Fragment B exists and is created when you send that event? Also, if you are using the most updated version of eventbus, you'll need a `@Subscribe` above `onEvent()`method.

Comment: @Amy no when I send event the `Fragment B` not exist, it is born after sending an Event

Comment: ... that doesn't ring a bell? The events are not stored in any way, if `Fragment B` is not created, there is no subscriber for your event. Easy Peasy. To make it work, you'll need a workaround, for example 'storing' the event in your `Activity`, creating `Fragment B` before you send the event. etc.

Comment: EventBus has a `StickyEvent`. Maybe this will fullfill your needs. [Documentation of StickyEvent](http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/documentation/configuration/sticky-events/)

Comment: EventBus provides a feature called stickyEvent. In this case these events are stored in EventBus, until someone would like to handle them. Has to be used with caution (leaks, ...)

Comment: @Amy can I use sticky event ? If yes, how can sticky and non sticky events live in the one fragment? I'm asking about register/unregister. Anyway thank you, the ring a bell :D

Comment: `StickyEvents` stay around, and are as far as I know just another type of `Event`. Please take a look at the Documentation (linked above), if you want to know more.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing this code in the MainActivity:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
    super.onStop();
}
```

Comment: in which fragment should I add this ?

Comment: does not work,  crushes! requires the host activity to be a subscriber as well